# How to express Azure File Share location using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-file-share

I am trying to modify current Powershell to point to Azure File Share.

Currently, bottom Powershell is used in a local drive, but I would like to change to pointing to Azure File Share.

```
param ( [String] $Filename  = '*.csv',
        [String] $SourceDir = 'C:\Test\',
        [String] $TargetDir = 'C:\Test\convert\'
)

ForEach ($csvFile in Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter $Filename){
    (Import-Csv $csvFile | 
     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|') -replace '[,"]' -replace '\|',',' |
         Set-Content (Join-Path $TargetDir $csvFile.Name)                  
}
```

I have used the bottom Python file that points to Azure File Share like below (for other project).

So, the goal is modify the top Powershell with something similar to Python code below:

How to express URL, account key in the existing Powershell?

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient, ShareClient, 
ShareDirectoryClient, ShareFileClient
import pandas as pd
import io

account_url = "https://example.file.core.windows.net"
account_key = "xxxx=="

service_client = ShareServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=account_key)
share_name = "testname"
share_client = service_client.get_share_client(share_name)

# Get a ShareDirectoryClient object to connect to the directory
directory_path = "Parent/Child"
directory_client = share_client.get_directory_client(directory_path)
```

What I am trying to do is connect the $ctx to the argument (ForEach(...) ):

Bottom is just an example of applying "Remove-AzDtalakeGen2Item" that I found from [this YouTube](https://youtu.be/4RD9duhYnoc?t=307):

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName = 'sample' -StorageAccountKey "xxxxxxxxx"
Remove-AzDatalakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem "sample" -Path "/Test/" -force
Remove-AzDatalakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem "Sample" -Path "/Test/Convert" -force
```

(1/12/2024):
This is an error message:
[image]

(1/16/2024):
[image]

(1/18/2024):
[image]

Passing values directly (1/18/2024)
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the cmdlets in the `Az.Storage` module, in particular: `Get-AzStorageContainer`, `Get-AzStorageBlob`, `Get-AzStorageFile`, etc

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I updated the content on the top (Update). I guess I need to connect $ctx (context info) with the argument (that starts with "ForEach"). Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess this is want you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110867/use-azure-file-share-in-powershell-runbook

Comment: @wp78de Thank you for your input. I looked at the code on that link, but I am still not sure how I could put all pieces together? I think, regards to $context, I could put username and password and create one, but I am not sure how to apply other folder paths (like $SourceDir, $TargetDir, and $Filename from my code). Can you possibly put the sample codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `Az.Storage` using `Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force -AllowClobber`

Here is the script youre looking for:

```
param (
    [String] $Filename  = '*.csv',
    [String] $SourceDir = 'Test',
    [String] $TargetDir = 'Test/convert'
)

$storageAccountName = "your-storage-account-name"
$storageAccountKey = "your-storage-account-key"
$shareName = "your-share-name"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

$allFiles = Get-AzStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $shareName -Path $SourceDir 
$csvFiles = $allFiles | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Filename }

ForEach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    $fileExists = Get-AzStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $shareName -Path "$TargetDir/$($csvFile.Name)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($null -eq $fileExists) {
        $content = Get-AzStorageFileContent -Context $ctx -ShareName $shareName -Path "$SourceDir/$($csvFile.Name)" |
                    Out-String |
                    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' |
                    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|' |
                    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '[,"]' -replace '\|',',' }

        Set-AzStorageFileContent -Context $ctx -ShareName $shareName -Path "$TargetDir/$($csvFile.Name)" -Value $content
    } else {
        Write-Host "File $($csvFile.Name) already exists in the Azure File Share."
    }
}
```

`Get-AzStorageFile` is used to check if a file with the same name already exists in the Azure File Share. If the file does not exist, `Get-AzStorageFile` will return `$null` and the script will upload the local file. If the file does exist, the script will print a message and skip the upload. Feel free to remove this part if you dont care about the files being rewritten.

Comment: Actually, I am not using local drive. Everything would be inside Azure File Share. So C:\Test\ and C:\Test\convert would not be applied. Those where listed just for an example.

Comment: No problem, I've updated the code for what you need, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I tried the code, and but I am not sure if it is anything to do with my setting in Azure Data Factory or not. Basically, Azure Data Factory executes a powershell. At this moment, it is not moving files into 'Test/convert' location. I probably need to check others. Your code appears to be legit though. I will probably get back to you tomorrow (after checking more). I have a question though.  You mentioned about 'install Az.Storage using Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force -AllowClobber". Do I have to do this even when I run inside Azure (using Azure Data Factory)?

Comment: In Azure Data Factory, you typically don’t need to manually install the `Az.Storage` module. Azure Data Factory should automatically ensure that these modules are available for your functions. Just in case, make sure you have this setup correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882577/install-powershell-modules-in-azure-function

Comment: Don't we have to use something similar to this "-Path "/Test/" -force (using -Path or using -force)?  I was watching YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RD9duhYnoc&t=307s) and it mentioned about -force.

Comment: Yes you're correct.

Comment: I am trying to test in my local machine if it works first. You mentioned that I need to install  Az.Storage using Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force -AllowClobber, correct?

Comment: Yes its this module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage

Comment: When I ran the (Install-Module -Name Az.Storage), it says Administrator rights are required to install. Do I have to have IT to install this? How do to back to root ( PS> )?

Comment: Yes you need to be an admin on your local PC and run PowerShell elevated, if you don't have permissions then your IT team will need to install it for you.

Comment: Is there command to go back to root  ( PS > ) from something like PS C:\Users\jdoe>  ?

Comment: Yes it should be in a global variable called `$home` so you can do `cd $home`

Comment: I tried both, but it still goes back to PS C:\Users\jdoe>  I will try asking IT to type the command.

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood, the command is cd\              home is your home aka C:\Users\jdoe

Comment: I am still debugging your code (because IT did not finish installing Az.Storage). But I think you deserve the bounty. I might have to ask you later more. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime, feel free to message me in chat so we dont make an extended discussion in the comments. I will update my answer if there's something to fix in the code.

Comment: Does the Powershell code using Powershell 7 or 5? My IT guy is asking. I am not confident with this IT guy, but he thinks that Powersehll 5 does not run Az command.

Comment: It should work fine with both versions, I would personally set it up in PS v5. Have him install it there and if there are any issues I can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I ran the code (after installation of Az.Storage), and I came across with an error. Please see an image on the content (Update (1/12/2024): on the top.

Comment: @Java Hello please see the updated code snippet.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code and tried again. It appears that now the error might be something to do with connecting to Azure (see updated error on the top). Let me dig in and see if I could possibly resolve. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Isazc I had a meeting with Microsoft support engineer last night, and tried the code. We were trying to go over code where Azure File Share folders were mentioned. There is no error message now, but files do not move. Nothing happened. Let me put the screenshot on the post now.

Comment: Hi @Java try passing the parameters needed for the script in the command line and let me know if it still not showing anything.

Comment: I just modified the code by passing the parameter values. It is same result. I am posting image on the top.